# Using Python markdown Treeprocessor to wrap an etree Element

Tags: python, markdown

I'm trying to write a Python markdown Treeprocessor extension that will wrap a `span` tag inside a `div` tag; so if I have (markdown) -

```
before <span>hello world</span> after
```

then post- processing I want to end up with -

```
before <div><span>hello world</span></div> after
```

Python markdown seems to have all these different processors you can use and extend -

https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/api/

I figured a TreeProcessor probably the best suited, and came up with the following -

```
from markdown.extensions import Extension

from markdown.treeprocessors import Treeprocessor

import markdown

class MyTreeProcessor(Treeprocessor):

    def run(self, doc):
        def iterate(parent):
            print ("%s %s :: %s" % (parent.tag, parent.attrib, parent.text))
            for child in parent.getchildren():
                iterate(child)
        iterate(doc)

class MyTreeExtension(Extension):

    def extendMarkdown(self,
                       md,
                       key="my_extension",
                       index=1e8):
        md.registerExtension(self)
        md.treeprocessors.register(MyTreeProcessor(md.parser),
                                   key, index)

if __name__=="__main__":
    md=markdown.Markdown(extensions=[MyTreeExtension()])
    md.convert("before <span>hello world</span> after")
```

but if I run it with index value `1e8` I get the following -

```
div {} :: None
p {} :: before <span>hello world</span> after
```

whilst if I run it with index value `0` I get the following -

```
div {} :: 

p {} :: before wzxhzdk:0hello worldwzxhzdk:1 after
```

Neither of these are what I want - in the first case the `span` hasn't been processed, in the second it has been processed in some kind of weird format :-/

Finding the markdown extension docs pretty turgid for what should seemingly be a simple task - could someone confirm that I am barking up the right tree in using a Treeprocessor here (or not), and if so what I am doing wrong in being unable to get this `span` parsed as an `etree.Element` ?

TIA

Comment: Curious why you used a priority of `1e8`? If I'm not mistaken, that equals `100000000.0`. However, there are only two builtin treeprocessors with priorities of `10` and `20`. You could have easily used any number higher than `20`. No need to use one hundred billion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to use a Treeprocessor here as you are working with raw HTML.

Python-Markdown parses Markdown by converting it to an `etree` object. However, it does not parse HTML (at least not completely) and `etree` objects cannot hold raw HTML strings. Well, they can hold them, but they will get escaped when the `etree` object gets rendered to an HTML string. Therefore, the raw HTML is identified and replaced with a placeholder (`wzxhzdk:0`). After the `etree` object is rendered to an HTML string, a postprocessor then finds all the placeholders and swaps them out for the raw HTML which was stored using the placeholder as a key.

The reason for the different behavior between your two indexes is that one of them is running before inlinepatterns are run (the first treeprocessor actually is a wrapper around all inlinepatterns) and the other is running after, but before the placeholders are swapped back in. Of course, as the placeholders are swapped back in by a postprocessor, you cannot access that state from a treepreprocessor.

In summary:

1. Block level raw HTML is handled by a preprocessor and will never be available from a treeprocessor.
2. Inline raw HTML is handled by an inlinepattern and so inline raw HTML will be unprocessed before the `inlineProcessor` treeprocessor runs, but will be unavailable from a treeprocessor after it runs.

A likely solution would be to use an inlinepattern. However, you will need to parse the HTML tags yourself.

Additionally, the output you desire is not valid HTML. Note that `before <span>hello world</span> after` would get wrapped in a `<p>` tag and `<p>` tags cannot hold any other block level elements, including `<div>` tags. Sure, there is nothing forcing you to not wrap a `<div>` tag in a `<p>` tag, but a browser will never interpret the HTML that way. According to the HTML spec, a block level tag automatically closes a `<p>` tag. Therefore, a browser will (probably) interpret your output something like this:

```html
<p>before </p><div><span>hello world</span></div> after<p></p>
```

Note that there is no `<p>` wrapping `after`. Yes, the closing tag would be present, but without the opening tag (immediately after the closing `</div>`, the browser wouldn't know were it starts and you would get an empty `<p>` where the widow closing tag is.

Now if you are okay with all this, then why not just use `<div>` in your Markdown to begin with. Or are `<span>` and `<div>` just placeholders in the question for actual tags in real life? If so, whether they are inline or block level could change the answer.

Comment: Well that's a terrific answer, thank you. I just used `<span>` and `<div>` as proxies for the actual situation. In fact I am trying to fix margining for Twitter embeds, which use `<blockquote class="twitter-tweet>`. I can't seem to add CSS styles for `blockquote.twitter-tweet` as the embed runs some JS on loading which seems to ignore any globally set styles. So the current workaround (as u suggest) is just to wrap the `<blockquote>` within a `<div class="my-twitter">` in the markdown. I was just wondering if an extension could insert `<div class="my-twitter">` but seems like lots of bother

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Note that `<blockquote>` is a block level tag, so it would behave differently than a `<span>` tag so long as it is on a line by itself.